# Why maven create folders on my project root?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

im facing this problem and I dont know what to do. We import a project from git to Intellij, and when we execute mvn clean install, maven start creating all dependencies folders on our project root. This only happpends on one of our PCs, and we have no idea why:

[image]

Any idea about how to solve this?
Thanks!
Update with settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <localRepository />
        <interactiveMode />
        <usePluginRegistry />
        <offline />
    <pluginGroups />
    <servers>
            <server>
                <username>xxxxxx</username>
                <id>xxxxx</id>
                <password>xxxxxx</password>
            </server>
    </servers>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
        <id>xxxx</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>xxxxx</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>10.36.|.xxxxx</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>xxx</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>xxxx</name>
            <url>xxxxxxx</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>xxx</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>xxxxx</name>
            <url>xxxxxx</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>artifactory</id>    
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>xxxxxx</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>xxxxxx</url>
                    <snapshots/>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>plugins-release</name>
                    <url>xxxxxx</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
                    <url>xxxxxx</url>
                    <snapshots />       
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                                        <id>central2</id>
                                        <url>
                     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
                    </url>
                                        <releases>
                                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        </releases>
                                        <snapshots>
                                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        </snapshots>
                                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>xxxx</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>xxx</id>
                    <name>xxxx</name>
                    <url>xxxxxx</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>

                <repository>
                                        <id>central2</id>
                                        <url>
                        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
                    </url>
                                        <releases>
                                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        </releases>
                                        <snapshots>
                                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        </snapshots>
                                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>xxxx</id>
                    <name>xxxxx</name>
                    <url>xxxxxxxx</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>xxxx</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Intellij

[image]

Comment: Executing `mvn clean install` of the same project on a different PC does not do this? What plugins are configured in the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: No, on a different PC does not do this. We got a really big pom.xml, is a big project, but its working on every pc an eviroment we got it

Comment: Is there any chance that this PC has configured the project folder as local repository? Can you take a look at `~/.m2/settings.xml` and `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml`? And any repository-related info in the parent pom.xml?

Comment: As commented below, adding the <localRepository>C:\Users\YourName\.m2\repository</localRepository> inside the settings.xml solved the issue. Add the tag just at the beginning of the file. Thanks, @Rodrigo for the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like maven is configured to use the project root/the current directory as the location for the local repository.

Check `settings.xml` in `~/.m2`, possibly rename it and try again.

Comment: We have no local repository config on settings.xml, we got only a config on intellij. Im going to try adding the local repository config on settings.xml. Thanks!

Comment: We solved it adding the local repository directory. I dont understand why this was never a problem on any other PC, but problem solve, thanks!